# Swift - Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm learning the Swift lang with a tutorial.

I'm using this code:

```
let hasPrefixAndSuffix: (String,String,String) -> Bool
{
  var hasPrefix = $0.hasPrefix($1)
  var hasSuffix = $0.hasSuffix($2)
  return hasPrefix && hasSuffix
}
```

and I've this error:

```
Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure.
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `=` which actually assigns that closure to the variable.

```
let hasPrefixAndSuffix: (String,String,String) -> Bool = {
  var hasPrefix = $0.hasPrefix($1)
  var hasSuffix = $0.hasSuffix($2)
  return hasPrefix && hasSuffix
}
```